# Does lodash shuffle provides even distribution?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I need a evenly distributed shuffle method for an array, but checking the docs I see no clear answer for it it is "truly random". It does a variant of the "Fisher-Yates", which is good, but internally uses Math.random() which may not be so good. I'm in a Typescript/Node.js environment.
Are their any good alternatives? Maybe even with seed support?
Thanks!

Comment: what does "truly random" mean in this context? uniformly random over all permutations? impossible to predict the next outcome given the prior ones?

Comment: @user3080953 It would be uniformly random. Currently it seems I'll need to implement my own "Fisher-Yates" with Mersenne Twister as the rng.

Comment: according to the docs, Math.random() should be approximately uniformly random (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.random), so the lodash method should be fine

Comment: According to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84906/predicting-math-random-numbers, browsers these days use [XorShift128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift.2B), which appears to be as good or better than Mersenne Twister. (Caveat: I know very little about this subject.)

Comment: See also http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/. I think you're better of sticking with the built-in `Math.random()` if you're after statistical quality.

Comment: I realize that the context of this question is Node.js, but I believe by virtue of V8 using XorShift128+, you should be good there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a evenly distributed shuffle … uses Math.random() which may not be so good

Don't worry, `Math.random` is perfectly uniformly distributed. What it does not have is [cryptographic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator), but you don't appear to need that. If you do, [`crypto.randomBytes`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) is your friend.